# Is the word assassinator legitimate?

Tags: meaning, etymology

I realize `assassin` is shorter and easier, but is `assassinator` a legitimate word? Is there any semantic difference between the two?

I realize in a historical context `assassin` can be used to refer to a member of the [Islamic Assassin sect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assassins), I'm curious about the more common 'murderer' definition.

Comment: "Assassinator" would be violating no rules about converting a verb to the corresponding "actor" noun.  It is, however, unusual, and may grate on the reader's nerves.  (In normal US English, "assassin" would refer only to someone who murders a specifically targeted individual, usually for religious or political reasons.  The more general meaning "murderer" would not be assumed, for either "assassin" or "assassinator".)

Comment: I also just checked both the COCA corpus and Google nGrams and each reports precisely 0 uses of *assassinator*, so I'd say between that and Hot Lick's comment and Josh's answer, the word is invalidated in both theory in practice. Bottom line: no.

Comment: Not exactly a definitive source, but there is a 'Assasinator' line of tires for ATVs

Comment: As a personator interested in language, I would objectionate (at least mentally) to this kind of usage if I heard another Englishonator  using it.

Comment: @DanBron - Actually, Ngram finds roughly 250 instances of "assassinator", the vast majority of which appear to be legitimate and not some artifact of the scan process.  Most appear to be prior to 1900, though.

Comment: @HotLicks Maybe I misspelled it when I typed it in? I got literally nothing.

Comment: Define "*legitimate*".

Comment: @Drew - Ngram has a tendency to pick up a pattern like, say, "assassinate her" and somehow read it as "assassinator".  It also might pick up 50 references for the "assassinator beetle" or some other irrelevant (for our purposes) use.  I didn't check every reference, but in the ones I looked at I saw no evidence of either problem.  The only real issue is that there appeared to be a number of repeated references, from articles presumably duplicated in various journals, etc.  But this doesn't weaken the claim of legitimacy unless virtually all uses are from a very few sources.

Comment: @Drew (Any time that an Ngram search is used as a source and the number of "hits" is small it's wise to examine a number of the actual references for such problems. It's simply good research practice.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***[Assassin](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=assassin&allowed_in_frame=0)*** is the original term, assassinator, a later term, comes from ***assassinate***. Assassinator is a  much less common term than assassin (see Ngram):

> - ***1530s (in Anglo-Latin from mid-13c.), via French and Italian, from Arabic hashishiyyin "hashish-users," plural of hashishiyy, from the source of hashish (q.v.).*** A fanatical Ismaili Muslim sect of the time of the Crusades, under leadership of the "Old Man of the Mountains" (translates Arabic shaik-al-jibal, name applied to Hasan ibu-al-Sabbah), with a reputation for murdering opposing leaders after intoxicating themselves by eating hashish. The plural suffix -in was mistaken in Europe for part of the word (compare Bedouin).

***[Assassinate](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=assassinate&allowed_in_frame=0):***

> - 1610s, from past participle stem of Medieval Latin ***assassinare (see assassin).*** "Assassinate means to kill wrongfully by surprise, suddenly, or by secret assault" [Century Dictionary]. Of reputations, characters, etc., from 1620s.

***[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=assassin%2C%20assassinator&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cassassin%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cassassinator%3B%2Cc0)***:  ***assassin vs assassinator***

[The Oxford Dictionary of American Usage and Style](https://books.google.it/books?id=z_VmtjAU01YC&pg=PA31&lpg=PA31&dq=assassinator%20usage%20oxford&source=bl&ots=6HePdl_-B-&sig=LB0sHmfAyO-fd4bOD4MHPyz8GKs&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiUxaKUk8HLAhUH8ywKHRMeD9kQ6AEILDAH#v=onepage&q=assassinator%20usage%20oxford&f=false) defines *assassinator* as an unnecessary variant of *assassin.*

(Etymonline)

Comment: Deleted my answer because yours has more information than mine does.

Comment: @sumelic Okay, undeleted just for you. :)

Answer (score 3):

Surprisingly to me because I wasn't expecting it to be, [turns out it is!](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/assassinator)

> ### ***Assassinator***
>
> a person who assassinates [Collins English Dictionary]

Example sentence:

> The assassinator comes just a month after Paraguay's congress voted to start impeachment proceedings against Mr Cubas. (not the best example I'd have thought of, but Collins is generally trustworthy so we'll go with it)

Comment: Looking at that quotation, I would bet a large amount that *assassination* was intended; possibly what was originally written and later garbled. Unfortunately, Collins gives no sources

Answer (score 1):

The [Oxford English Dictionary](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/11737?redirectedFrom=assassinator#eid0) has eight entries for ***assassinator***, the most recent from the year 2000 about Gov. George Wallace.  I give them all, because the OED is behind a pay-wall.

> An assassin.
>
> 1651   H. Parker Scotlands Holy War 3   Some Noblemen that were
>   invited to a bloodie supper, got timely advertisement of the royall
>   assassinators, and so by flying privily out of Edenburgh secured
>   themselves.
>
> 1656   S. Hunton Golden Law 9   Oh you his immediate Assasinators, you
>   Madmen, you Murtherers.
>
> 1704   London Gaz. No. 4029/3   Looked upon..as Assassinators.
>
> 1726   D. Defoe Polit. Hist. Devil ii. vii. 286   No less than a
>   King-Killer and an Assassinator.
>
> 1820   Monthly Mag. May 367/2   Thistlewood, one of the proposed
>   assassinators,..was the first person tried.
>
> 1897   Gentleman Farmer Feb. 127   We need..a curculio buster,
>   a..potato bug assassinator.
>
> 1920   J. T. Tussaud Romance Madame Tussaud's xxxiv. 241   We saw a
>   room in which were the images of almost all the assassinators with the
>   particulars of their deeds.
>
> 2000   J. Lavery in C. Bush et al. Journey Prize Anthol. 148   The
>   assassinators, after a string of glorious successes, had managed only
>   to disable as motionless a target as George Wallace

Answer (score 0):

*Assassinator* specifically refers to someone involved in an actual and successful assassination i.e. the culprit to a murder case. *Assassin* pertains to someone employed to kill people (regardless if they have or have not yet successfully assassinated anyone in the past.)
Example sentence using the two words in context:

> The crown prince has been assassinated last night. The assassinator turned out to be an assassin hired by the prince's own brother.

This nuance is similar in spirit to the difference between a *teacher* (someone whose profession is in education) and an *educator* (someone who actually educates students).

Comment: This directly contradicts OED's statement that the two are synonyms, one extremely rare. Usage, not logic, determines the meaning of words.